# Why the third function doesn't get called in a pipeK when all of them are futures?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, applicative, ramda-fantasy

I can't figure out why the third function (i.e. `doStuff3`) isn't being called, so the `console.log` on fork should print `"hello world!!!!"`

```
const 
  doStuff = () => Future.of(["hello", "world"]),
  doStuff2 = (x, y) => Future((resolve, reject) => resolve(`${x} ${y}`)),
  doStuff3 = x => Future.of(`${x}!!!!`)

pipeK(doStuff, apply(doStuff2), doStuff3)().fork(console.log, console.error)
```

You can run it on [Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.25.0#?const%20doStuff%20%3D%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20Future.of%28%5B%22hello%22%2C%20%22world%22%5D%29%0Aconst%20doStuff2%20%3D%20%28x%2C%20y%29%20%3D%3E%20Future%28%28resolve%2C%20reject%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20resolve%28%60%24%7Bx%7D%20%24%7By%7D%60%29%20%7D%29%0Aconst%20doStuff3%20%3D%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20Future.of%28%60%24%7Bx%7D%21%21%21%21%60%29%0A%0ApipeK%28doStuff%2C%20apply%28doStuff2%29%2C%20doStuff3%29%28%29.fork%28console.log%2C%20console.error%29%20%20%20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Future doesn't suck like Promise**

The broken Promise API allows you to `then` without handling errors

```
 // uh, what happens if there's a problem ?
 myPromise .then (console.log)

 // proper use, but nothing forces you to specify 2nd argument
 myPromise .then (console.log, console.error)
```

Of course you could `.catch`, but people often forget about that too – Future doesn't have these problems ...

---

Future forces you to specify the error path by making that the first parameter – in both the executor *and* the `fork`'ing function

```
const f1 = (...xs) =>
  Future.of (xs)

const f2 = (x, y) =>
  Future ((reject, resolve) => // REJECT comes first
    resolve (x + y))

const f3 = x =>
  Future.of (`${x} !!!`)

const myFuture =
  pipeK (f1, apply (f2), f3)
    ("hello", "world")

               // ERROR path first
myFuture.fork (console.error, console.log)
// logs: "helloworld !!!"
// returns: undefined
```

Comment: Shit, at the end of the day it was I as putting `resolve` first... :D Anyway, thank you for the explanation :)